# Referring to Button on Form with String VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In my program (VB.NET), I am trying to create a loop that looks something like this:

```
Dim NumberOfRows As Integer = IPOSDBDataSet.Meals.Rows.Count
Dim IntegerCount As Integer = 1
Do Until IntegerCount = NumberOfRows
    Button("ButtonMeal" & IntegerCount).Text = "Hello"
    'AND MORE STUFF
Loop
```

I know that the Button line doesn't work, but this is the best way of describing how I would like it to work. I am using a database with my program. I want a loop to go through and change (for example) the text property of a button.

On the first loop, it would change "ButtonMeal1" text to "Hello". Then, if there are more rows on the table, it would loop and change "ButtonMeal2" to "Hello" and so on. Obviously, I don't want to change everything to hello, but I am trying to keep my code simplistic as to avoid confusion.

If this does not make sense, please tell me. I have been looking for hours and hours and cannot find an answer! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Find Method of the Control Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx), this function will search the children of the Control Collection, just incase your buttons are hosted on a Panel or another container Control.

```
DirectCast(Controls.Find("ButtonMeal" & IntegerCount, True)(0), Button).Text = "Hello"
```

Comment: I just used your method, and it WORKS!!!! Thank you so much for solving my problem. It is gonna take me an hour to understand everything that it does, but I will get there! Thanks for making my life so much easier!

Comment: Sorry, just one more thing, is it possible to use the method when on a different form. What I mean is on Form 2, can I use this code to refer to a button on Form 1? On Form 2 code, Form1.DirectCast doesn't work?

Comment: @Joshua You would need to have a reference to your other Form, you would then use something like `DirectCast(Form1.Controls.Find(.......))`. I personally would prefer to use an event / subscriber model. that way each form does not have awareness of the internals of the other form.

Comment: @Joshua make sure you use the reference you create not the Form Class itself

Answer (score 1):

Try like this ..

```
Dim btn as Button
Do Until IntegerCount = NumberOfRows
    btn=DirectCast(Controls("ButtonMeal" & IntegerCount.ToString),Button)
    btn.Text = "Hello"
    'AND MORE STUFF
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the name of a control in the controlCollection like:

```
Me.Controls("ButtonMeal" & IntergerCount.ToString)
```

If they belong to another container:

```
Panel1.Controls("ButtonMeal" & IntergerCount.ToString)
```

If your control is named ButtonMeal1, etc...

If you use a strongly typed dataset, you can bind to controls at design time - might be a better design.

Comment: I think I saw that somewhere else, and tried it, but I get this error; NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, if you get the name wrong that is the error you will get.

Comment: But I am certain that I have the right name. I even tried without the & IntegerCount and just put "ButtonMeal1", but still get the error. Do I have to declare it or something? I have the button on my form, but is this not enough?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what you mean by a strongly typed dataset?

Comment: Yes, the button is called "ButtonMeal1", with "ButtonMeal2" and "ButtonMeal3" and so on.

Comment: Do the controls belong to the form or are they nested inside of a container?

Comment: They are in a Panel, which is in TabControl, which Is in a TableLayoutPanel, which is in another TableLayoutPanel. Confusing I know, but I have a feeling we might have just discovered the issue.

Comment: I updated my post. Use the control collection for the buttons or use the Find method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I now understand what the problem is, and have fixed it! THANKS!!!